# Edittext focus is automatically disabled after single rfid card scanned

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, rfid

I have a app which is based on RFID reader and providing data is based on that tags. my layout view contains the edittext which has the Listener **OnEditorActionListener** to read rfid tags and Gridview to show the calendar (customised calendar).Listener and editText is everything working fine upto Jellybean 4.3.
but am facing problem only in kitkat (4.4) .In KitKat i can read only single card after that the edittext focus is disabled automatically. I can't scan/read the second card .

Listener Code:

```
    editText_readRfid
            .setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
                    actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
                    event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                    event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                        if (!event.isShiftPressed()) {
                            rfidData = editText_readRfid.getText()
                                    .toString();
                            editText_readRfid.getText().clear();                
                            if (mLinkedHashMap.containsKey(rfidData))
                            {
                                String timeStamp = (String) mLinkedHashMap
                                        .get(rfidData);
                                if (Util.checkTimeDifference(
                                        timeStamp,
                                        Util.getCurrentTimeStamp())) {

                                    mLinkedHashMap.put(rfidData,
                                        Util.getCurrentTimeStamp());
                                displayDetails(rfidData);

                                }

                                else {
                                    Util.showmessage(context, "Alert",
                                                    "You have already swiped the card");
                                }
                            }
                            else {

                                mLinkedHashMap.put(rfidData,
                                        Util.getCurrentTimeStamp());
                                displayStudentDetails(rfidData);
                            }
                            return true; // consume.
                        }
                    }
                    return false; // pass on to other listeners
                }

            });
```

after the focus disabled ,i tried this, inside edittext cursor blinking but no response

```
editText_readRfid.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() 
         {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Focus :" + hasFocus,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    v.requestFocus();
                    v.setSelected(true);
                    v.setFocusable(true);

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

After swiping the card am showing records and am updating gridview also so that focus went to Gridview.for that i disabled the Gridview cell(Button) focus and now its working fine.

```
gridcell.setFocusable(false);
```